# How to select records from mysql along with one previous record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this

```
+----+----------------------+------------+
| id | desc                 | date       |
+----+----------------------+------------+
| 15 | nah_i_kid            | 2017-06-07 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
| 17 | it_is_just_the_cat   | 2017-06-08 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
| 18 | thank_God            | 2017-06-09 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
| 44 | no_kidding           | 2017-06-10 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
```

My sql is

> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date between '2017-06-09' AND '2017-06-12'

I want the result should contain one previous record also (i-e record having id=17 take it example)
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use UNION with a query that grabs that extra record; there is no special syntax for what you want. Also, if your `date` field is not unique, that unioned query will need to account for which to pick if there is more than one.

Comment: Sorry! I dont want to use pagination its simple few records which I needed but i need a single previous record along with output of statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MYSQL, I have tried and it work good.

```
(select * from table where date < '2017-06-09' order by date desc limit 1 ) union (select * from table where date between '2017-06-09' AND '2017-06-12' order by date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the records from the previous date, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where date > (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.date < '2017-06-09') and
      date <= '2017-06-12';
```

This does what you want, assuming you have no duplicates on a date.

If you want exactly one row and you know the ids are assigned in chronological order, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where id > (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.date < '2017-06-09') and
      date <= '2017-06-12';
```

This solves the problem by taking the most recent previous record based on `id`.

If the ids are not in chronological order and you can have duplicates, the query gets more difficult.  There is no definition of the "previous record".  A `union all` is the best solution:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where date < '2017-06-09'
 order by date desc
 limit 1
) union all
select t.*
from t
where date > >= '2017-06-09' and
      date <= '2017-06-12'
```

Comment: @RehanAli . . . Interesting that you accepted an answer with essentially the same code posted almost an hour after this one.

Comment: Sorry! @Gordon i tried your answer but the response was you have error in sql, but for that answer it give me no error therefore i accept that one

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

The first part of the query is identical to yours, the second part gets all the values before your first date `2017-06-09`, orders the values by `date DESC`, then limits the query to only take the topmost value using `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT
    *
  FROM table
  WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2017-06-09' AND '2017-06-12'
    OR `id` = (
      SELECT
          `id`
        FROM table
        WHERE `date` < '2017-06-09'
        ORDER BY `date` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

> I want the result should contain one previous record also (i-e record having id=17 take it example)

If you know that the rows are created in chronological order, and your id field is auto-increment, then you don't even need to use the date field, because you can assume that a higher id indicates a later record. So just cap your search on the id you want, and grab two rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id <= 17 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
```

This has the added benefit of being fully indexed, which may not be the case if you introduce a `WHERE` clause on the date field.

Comment: Sorry! here i dont know about id as it is random. i have took 17 as an example